# adding JSON object to an existing array in external file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to add new JSON object to an array which is present in an external file.
I am unable to figure out how to do that.

I use push method which is only updating array ,but changes are not being reflected in external file.

index.js

```
const expres=require('express');
const exphnd=require('express-handlebars');
const students=require('./students_data');
const fs=require('fs');
const uuid=require('uuid');

app=expres();
const port=5000;

app.engine('handlebars', exphnd({defaultLayout:'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(expres.json());
app.use(expres.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/welcome',(req,res) => {
    res.render('welcome');
});

app.get('/register',(req,res) => {
    res.render('register');
});

app.post('/register',(req,res) => {

    var name_reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var rol_reg= /^[0-9]*$/;
    var marks_reg = /^[0-9]*$/; 
    if(req.body.name.match(name_reg) && (req.body.std ==='SE'|| req.body.std ==='TE' || req.body.std ==='BE') && req.body.rollno.match(rol_reg) && req.body.marks.match(marks_reg))
    {          
          var newstud={
            id:uuid.v4(),
            name:req.body.name,
            std:req.body.std,
            rol_no:req.body.rollno,
            marks:req.body.marks
          };     
          students.push(newstud);
          res.json(students);
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).json({msg:'some data is wrong'});
    }
});

app.get('/dashboard',(req,res) =>{
    res.render('dashboard',{stud_arr:students});
    console.log(students);
});
           
//create a server on port 5000
app.listen(5000,(req,res) => {
    console.log('server is listening');
})
```

external file in which array is present

```
var students=[
    {
        id:1,
        name:"bhagyashri",
        std:"TE",
        rol_no:45,
        marks:66
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:"zxc",
        std:"SE",
        rol_no:57,
        marks:76
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:"qwe",
        std:"SE",
        rol_no:57,
        marks:76
    }
];

module.exports=students;
```

**output after registering new student**

```
server is listening
    [
      { id: 1, name: 'bhagyashri', std: 'TE', rol_no: 45, marks: 66 },
      { id: 2, name: 'zxc', std: 'SE', rol_no: 57, marks: 76 },
      { id: 3, name: 'qwe', std: 'SE', rol_no: 57, marks: 76 },
      {
        id: '37776edf-9e0d-435c-a976-79b270d3bcc1',
        name: 'purva',
        std: 'TE',
        rol_no: '34',
        marks: '78'
      }
    ]
```

but, new record with id **37776edf-9e0d-435c-a976-79b270d3bcc1** is not added to students.js.

can anyone please tell me how to add that ?

Comment: Since you're model's data is static, I think the only option is to dynamically re-write the model file with the updated students array.

Comment: but i won't able to rewrite module.exports=students; and var student everytime i rewrite.please tell me how to do that

Comment: Exactly. This is why developers use a database. If you're not willing to use a database, you can use a datafiles approach. Have a csv-file with the data, and in "./students_data" simply open the file and read it, organise it as a JS object and export it. the same goes for updating it.

Comment: insted i will use mongoDB

Comment: Great, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't save data into the file. So the new record will never appears in the file.

I suggest you use `fs.readFileSync()` method instead of `requre()` function to load the file which you stored data. And keep data in pure JSON format just like this:

`students_data.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bhagyashri",
    "std": "TE",
    "rol_no": 45,
    "marks": 66
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "zxc",
    "std": "SE",
    "rol_no": 57,
    "marks": 76
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "qwe",
    "std": "SE",
    "rol_no": 57,
    "marks": 76
  }
]
```

Because `fs.readFileSync()` method load file as text, so it is necessary to use `JSON.parse()` method to convert JSON text into javascript objects.
Use `JSON.stringify()` method to convert javascript objects into JSON text and call `fs.writeFileSync()` method to save data into file.

Code like this:

```js
// load and parse data
var students = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./students_data.json'));

// your codes

var newstud = {
  // all the property
}
students.push(newstud);
// stringify and save data to file
fs.writeFileSync('./students_data.json', JSON.stringify(students));
```

Relative paths which passed in `fs.readFileSync()` will be resolved relative to the current working directory as determined by calling `process.cwd()`. It is different to `require()`

One more thing, it is better to use database store data if you read and write data frequently

Answer (score 0):

You load data from your file `const students = require('./students_data')` but your array is not linked to your file. Updating `student` will not magically update your file, you have to re-write it.